# Winforms combobox displaying class names instead of actual object name

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have this class that contains a static list

```
public class TypeList
{
    public string Name;
    public string NameTag;

    public TypeList(string Name, string NameTag)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.NameTag = NameTag;
    }

    public static List<TypeList> DataType = new List<TypeList>() {
        new TypeList("DataType","-1"),
        new TypeList("OpOne","1"),
        new TypeList("OpTwo","2"),
    };
}
```

I then put the static list called DataType into a combobox:

```
public void RefreshList()
{
    List<TypeList> data = new List<TypeList>();
    data = TypeList.DataType;

    typeCB.DataSource = data;
    typeCB.DisplayMember = "Name";
    typeCB.ValueMember = "NameTag";
    typeCB.SelectedValue = -1;
    typeCB.SelectedText = "Select DataType";
}
```

However, when I run it, all I get are the classnames in my combobox. Is something wrong with my code? I tried to do

> data.Select(x=>x.Name).ToList()

But that just gives me the name portion.

Comment: If it gives you class names, something is propably using Object.ToString(). Returning the clas name is it's default implementation. | I am pretty sure the WinForm Combo box could not handle raw collections.  You have to create and add the CB items one at time from the source collection. But that might just be my faulty knowledge.

Comment: But if thats the case why is there a DisplayMember and ValueMember?

Comment: Nevermind what I said. My memory was dead wrong, CB does have this process.

Comment: I do not however that the example uses (readonly) properties. As this code has to use Reflection (no other way to get a variable via the string), it might be limited to work with properties. But again, not my area of expertise. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong, but based on the Documentation and [Example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember) it might be that this Feature only works with public property getters, not public fields:

> Gets or sets the **property** to display for this ListControl.

```
public class USState
{
    private string myShortName;
    private string myLongName;

    public USState(string strLongName, string strShortName)
    {

        this.myShortName = strShortName;
        this.myLongName = strLongName;
    }

    public string ShortName
    {
        get
        {
            return myShortName;
        }
    }

    public string LongName
    {

        get
        {
            return myLongName;
        }
    }

}
```

Of course I would also advise against making the list a part of the Type class. A simple Programm scope static would be better. If that is the case and as autoproties have have become a thing by now, this should be enough of a fix:

```
public class Type
{
public string Name { private set; get } ;
public string NameTag {private set; get };

    public TypeList(string Name, string NameTag)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.NameTag = NameTag;
    }

}



//use in the class of main, the form or some similar central point
static List<Type> TypeList = new List<Type>();
```